# config module missing property

Tags: node.js, express, cloudinary

I have a cloudinary config module:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
var config = require('./config.json')[app.get('env')];

module.exports = function(){
    cloudinary.config({
        cloud_name: config.cloudinary_cloud_name,
        api_key: config.cloudinary_api_key,
        api_secret: config.cloudinary_api_secret
    });

    return cloudinary;
};
```

and I use it:

```
var cloudinary = require('../config/cloudinary');

cloudinary.uploader.upload(file.path, function (result) {
```

I got this error:

```
Cannot read property 'upload' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do the `require('../config/cloudinary')` it's not executing the function. You can use it like this:

```
var cloudinary = require('../config/cloudinary')();

cloudinary.uploader.upload(file.path, function (result) {
```